# Unable to connect to container created by TestContainers in a SpringTest

Tags: spring-test, testcontainers

I'm using TestContainers to test a service class that will use mongodb. But Spring cannot connect to the mongodb created by the test container even I configured the `DynamicPropertySource`. It will just try to connect to my local mongo db instance.

Annotations for test class:

```kotlin
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation::class)
```

Configuration

```kotlin
@Autowired lateinit var taskService: PersistentTaskService

    companion object {
        @Container
        val mongoDbContainer: MongoDBContainer = MongoDBContainer("mongo:5.0.3")

        @DynamicPropertySource
        fun setUpProp(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry) {
            registry.add("spring.data.mongodb.uri", mongoDbContainer::getReplicaSetUrl)
        }
    }
```

How can I tell Spring to connect to the test container?

Answer (score 0):

All right, I found out why.

The configuration above has no problem. The reason why Spring is still connecting to my local database is that the MongoDB configuration is hardcoded as a bean (in src/main).

I just removed the bean and opted for a configuration file instead.